# Logout script doesn't work when redirection is set

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I have the following log-out script:

```
setcookie("key", "", time() - 36000);
setcookie("usr_email", "", time() - 36000);
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://www.site.net/");
```

When I like to that page directly (logout.php) it works great and logs the user out.

But for some reason, when I use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^log-out /logout.php
```

I can see that the redirection works, but the log-out is not being carried out.

EDIT: just checked, after being redirected back to the homepage, the cookies are still available. Just a clarification, if I go directly to the logout php file it works great.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you go through the PHP file? Remove the redirection and print something instead of it, then try and see if it still redirects.

Comment: @Martti I changed the redirect to location: http://www.site.net/?a and I can see that the redirection works, if that's what you mean

Comment: what are your caching settings, do you have memcached installed on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that hyphen in your htaccess file. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^log\-out /logout.php
```

Could you also tell the errors/behaviour that happens?

**Edit:**
The problem is in your PHP then. First of all, I'd recommend storing login-related data in sessions, not cookies. Cookies can be added and edited by users.

Anyway, the code should successfully clear, if not delete, the cookies. So it may be that you're checking if you're logged in based on if the cookies exist, rather than their content. In this case try `if(empty($_COOKIE['key']))`, which will check if it's empty or not.

To remove a cookie completely: `unset($_COOKIE['key'])`.

By the way, `session_destroy()` is not related to cookies at all.

**Edit 2:**
Try assigning the cookie to your domain and all its subdomains (including www):

```
setcookie('key', '', time() - 36000, '/', '.mysite.net');
```

Do the same when adding the cookies.

Comment: That didn't fix it.. there's no errors or anything, it does redirect me to the homepage, but it doesn't delete the cookies. I'm still logged in after the redirection

Comment: I changed the setcookie to unset(), but I'm getting the same results. Also, how is it possible that when linking directly to the .php file works but it doesn't when I use the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^log\-out logout.php
```

Set RewriteBase to your base url : hope you know this.